# Exception handling library for all micro services

Tags: java, exception

We are working on a micro services based project.I want to create a library for exception handling which we want to import in all my micro services. So that I dont have to write same/similar set of code for each service.

I know the usage of controller advices and customizing rest response in spring.

But I am not sure how should I convert them into a library.

Any help or pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a build tool, such as Maven or Gradle?  That informs the best way to split out the library.

Comment: Any pointers or links ??

Comment: This depends entirely on the frameworks you're using and how you're implementing the microservices.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a separate java project, move your validation logic into the java project, and you should be able to build the project into a jar file, import it back into your parent project and use it as a library like that.